# How to get cell name in this case?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview

In standard method `DataBindingComplete` I iterate rows/cols like as:

```
for (int row = 0; row < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; column++)
    {
        object value = dataGridView1[column, row].Value;
        if (value != null && value.GetType() == typeof(string))
        {
            (...)
        }
    }
}
```

How to check cell name like as?

I tried to do this:

```
if (dataGridView1[column, row].Name == "name") 
{
}
```

**Edit 1**
When I use `CellFormatting` then all cells start jumping after horizontal scrolling. Seems something wrong with rendering. Look at pic.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean column name?

Comment: have you tried `dataGridView1.Colums[column].Name`. I think this is working.

Comment: Yes, column name

Comment: I tried, but it returns me an error: `System.StackOverflowException occurred
  HResult=0x800703E9
`

Comment: That is probably an endless loop. What are you doing in the `if` statment?

Comment: I need to check if this cell in column with name `dataGridViewTextBoxColumn45` if yes, then to replace value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wire `CellFormatting` event and try following code for changing the value of the cell.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "dataGridViewTextBoxColumn45")
        e.Value = "oleg";
}
```

Comment: I can not use cellFormatting, because when I scroll datagrid it is works bad. Rendering does not work incorrect.

Comment: Look at pic in question, what happens when I use formatting, all cell jump

Comment: Now it is available

Comment: Can you check this?

Comment: can you use dropbox or equivalent?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152575/discussion-between-opv-and-dimos-k).